# hello . when i put list-view in a fragment the app doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin

When I put list-view in a fragment the app doesn't work. Here is my code so far:

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    var i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    var TheList      = arrayOf("Line1","Line2")
    var TheAdapter   = ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TheList)
    ListView.adapter = TheAdapter
    return i
}
```

Comment: ListView is not initialized I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have better luck if you override onViewCreated and move your initializations to that like so.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view:View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
var TheList = arrayOf("Line1","Line2")
var TheAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TheList) ListView.adapter = TheAdapter
}
```

The onviewCreated is where you do all your business at.